# tolua++ access structure member with properties

Tags: c++, lua, tolua++

I was trying to access structure member without property at first something like this:

Main file:

```
typedef struct
{
    char    var1[15];
    char    var2[33];
} my_struct_t;

class MyClass {
    MyClass()  { }
    ~MyClass() { }

    my_struct_t     my_struct;
};
```

pkg file:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass ()  { }
    ~MyClass () { }
    my_struct_t     my_struct;
};

typedef struct
{
    tolua_property char var1[15];
    tolua_property char var2[33];
} my_struct;
```

But it didn't work, the problem was in converting char arry into lua string, I couldn't set var1 as I expected because it was char arry instead of lua string which throws me error: "value is 'string'; 'table' expected.".
Ok then I added properties to these variables to able to access them as here:

```
typedef struct
{
    string get_var1()
    {
    // const char* can be also used instead of std::string to pass this as string into a lua?
        string str = var1;
        return str;
    }
    string get_var2() {
        string str = var2;
        return str;
    }
    void set_var1(string p_name) {
        strncpy(var1, p_name.c_str(), sizeof(var1));
        var1[sizeof(var1) - 1] = 0;
    }
    void set_var2(string p_name) {
        strncpy(var2, p_name.c_str(), sizeof(var2));
        var2[sizeof(var2) - 1] = 0;
    }
    char    var1[15];
    char    var2[33];
} my_struct_t;
```

**Problem**: As you can see I added properties to able to access these variables and to resolve char arry conversion but even it still throws me "value is 'string'; 'table' expected." which I don't understand why? Is it bug maybe or am I doing it wrong?
lua code:

```lua
local packet  = MyClass:new()
packet.my_struct.var1 = "hi"    -- throws "value is 'string'; 'table' expected." even with property
print(packet.my_struct.var1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, there is problem inside tolua++ parser which making anyway default variable property even if you declare your own, for example:

```
tolua_function(tolua_S,"set_var1",  tolua_lua_api_my_struct_t_set_var100); // my own property
tolua_function(tolua_S,"set_var2",  tolua_lua_api_my_struct_t_set_var200); // my own property
tolua_variable(tolua_S,"var1",  tolua_get_my_struct_t_var1, tolua_set_my_struct_t_var1); // default property
tolua_variable(tolua_S,"var2",  tolua_get_my_struct_t_var2, tolua_set_my_struct_t_var2); // default property
```

When you want to assign your variable in LUA default property will be called as primary.

To solve that problem there is two ways actually, just to remove your custom property and change tolua recognize function iside tolua_set_my_struct_t_var1 callback or remove default property and just use custom property as default.